# Use varnish cache for magento 2 and prestashop on one server

Tags: prestashop, magento2, varnish

I want to use varnish cache for magento 2 and prestashop on one server. I ask my friend but he told me can't do it. Because they have different configure. Can i install vanish cache and use it for only magento or for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Varnish on one server to use for both Magento2 and Prestashop.

However I suspect that both Magento2 and Prestashop will have some special config needed in Varnish. Therefore the VCL will be a  bit more complex.

Assuming that Magento2 and Prestashop are used on different hosts, you can add logic in your VCL based on the domain name if the configs are conflicting

```
if(bereq.http.host == "magento-host.com") {
  // specific config for magento
}
if(bereq.http.host == "prestashop-host.com") {
  // specific config for prestashop
}
```

Comment: I can't check it, now. Thanks.